# Не работает uppercase - Sass

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, sass

Не применяется апперкейс для:

```
&_subtitle
    сolor: #ffffff
    font-size: 24px
    font-weight: 400
    line-height: 31px
    text-transform: uppercase
    text-align: center
```

Если  прописать в html капсом - на странице видны изменения. Не могу понять в чем причина, есть идеи? Скрин:

[image: sass.style]

Comment: в инспекции кода данный стиль виден? зачеркнут?

Comment: нет, не виден, есть например text-align, но text-transform нет

Comment: проблема решена, перенесла text-transform после text-align

Comment: порядок свойств не зависит. Скорее всего не был сохранен файл

Comment: да, вы правы, поменяла еще раз местами и если файл сохранен, то все применяется. Действительно по невнимательности забыла сохранить. Спасибо!